# ARM template throws "Shared throughput collection should have a partition key"

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb, azure-resource-manager, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to create a cosmosdb account with shared throughput, I have the partition key mentioned in the ARM, but it doesn’t seem to take this when creating container.

```
"properties": {
        "resource": {
          "id": "[variables('cosmosDbContainers')[copyIndex()]]"
        },
        "partitionKey": {
          "paths": [
            "/id"
          ],
          "kind": "Hash"
        },
        "indexingPolicy": {
          "indexingMode": "consistent",
          "automatic": true,
          "includedPaths": [
            {
              "path": "/*"
            }
          ],
          "excludedPaths": [
            {
              "path": "/\"_etag\"/?"
            }
          ]
        },
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that the [tag:arm] tag is for questions about the ARM (Advanced RISC Machine) CPU architecture; the tag you want here is [tag:azure-resource-manager].  I made the change. Please check the descriptions of tags when you add them; sometimes they don't mean what you may guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the placement of partitionKey in the ARM is wrong, it should be under
the **`"resource"`** key

```
 "resource": {
            "id": "[variables('cosmosDbContainers')[copyIndex()]]",
            "partitionKey": {
                "paths": [
                    "/ipCountryCode"
                ],
                "kind": "Hash"
            }
        },
```